# Rails morris.js charts not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, charts, morris.js

Im trying to make the charts work in my HRM app using morris.js & javascript ...coffescript does not work for me according to the railcasts episode charts episode as it  breaks my entire app ...so cant use it ... :(  ...

Well this is my ERB file (gist) ... https://gist.github.com/SkyKOG/5261972

And this is how the chart would appear https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXZdI.png ...do notice that the JSON is appearing correctly but for now im stupidly just hard-coding the json data in the morris script tag (please see the gist) ... instead of using **$('#genders_chart').data('emp_spec_views')** as shown in the episode (which dosent display anything for me)...

So i needed to know how to get the data in the script correctly so that the graph is rendered correctly ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally for it working and thought i should post here for other's benefit :) ...

https://github.com/oesmith/morris.js/issues/204

Credits : tiraeth ...